# Convert a list of lists into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am trying to convert a list of lists which looks like the following into a Pandas Dataframe

```
[['New York Yankees ', '"Acevedo Juan"  ', 900000, ' Pitcher\n'], 
['New York Yankees ', '"Anderson Jason"', 300000, ' Pitcher\n'], 
['New York Yankees ', '"Clemens Roger" ', 10100000, ' Pitcher\n'], 
['New York Yankees ', '"Contreras Jose"', 5500000, ' Pitcher\n']]
```

I am basically trying to convert each item in the array into a pandas data frame which has four columns. What would be the best approach to this as pd.Dataframe does not quite give me what I am looking for.

Answer (score 89):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [['New York Yankees', 'Acevedo Juan', 900000, 'Pitcher'], 
        ['New York Yankees', 'Anderson Jason', 300000, 'Pitcher'], 
        ['New York Yankees', 'Clemens Roger', 10100000, 'Pitcher'], 
        ['New York Yankees', 'Contreras Jose', 5500000, 'Pitcher']]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

Comment: You could refine it a bit more with:

DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=['Team', 'Player', 'whatever-stat-is-that', 'position'])

Comment: Is there a way to specify the imports more specifically? E.g. I want to specify that `DataFrame["Team"]` must refer to the first item of each sublist (i.e. `data[i][0]`) and `DataFrame["Position"]` to refer to the last item of each sublist (i.e. `data[i][-1]`)?

Comment: @Ivo: Use the `columns` parameter of [DataFrame.from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html).

Answer (score 22):

Once you have the data:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [['New York Yankees ', '"Acevedo Juan"  ', 900000, ' Pitcher\n'], 
        ['New York Yankees ', '"Anderson Jason"', 300000, ' Pitcher\n'], 
        ['New York Yankees ', '"Clemens Roger" ', 10100000, ' Pitcher\n'], 
        ['New York Yankees ', '"Contreras Jose"', 5500000, ' Pitcher\n']]
```

You can create dataframe from the transposing the data:

```py
data_transposed = zip(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_transposed, columns=["Team", "Player", "Salary", "Role"])
```

Another way:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = ["Team", "Player", "Salary", "Role"]
```

Comment: Your transposition example fails for me with "ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns". Why the transposition anyway when this works: `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Team", "Player", "Salary", "Role"])`.

Answer (score 7):

You can just directly define it as a data frame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['New York Yankees', 'Acevedo Juan', 900000, 'Pitcher'], 
        ['New York Yankees', 'Anderson Jason', 300000, 'Pitcher'], 
        ['New York Yankees', 'Clemens Roger', 10100000, 'Pitcher'], 
        ['New York Yankees', 'Contreras Jose', 5500000, 'Pitcher']]

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one by far was the simplest:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [['New York Yankees', 'Acevedo Juan', 900000, 'Pitcher'], 
        ['New York Yankees', 'Anderson Jason', 300000, 'Pitcher'], 
        ['New York Yankees', 'Clemens Roger', 10100000, 'Pitcher'], 
        ['New York Yankees', 'Contreras Jose', 5500000, 'Pitcher']]

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

now, if the keys are the first list in the list of lists (data[0]), you can assign them to column headers in the dataframe like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [['key1', 'key2', key3, 'key4'], 
    ['New York Yankees', 'Anderson Jason', 300000, 'Pitcher'], 
    ['New York Yankees', 'Clemens Roger', 10100000, 'Pitcher'], 
    ['New York Yankees', 'Contreras Jose', 5500000, 'Pitcher']]

data = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```